# Comparing Word documents and creating a new document with track changes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, comparison

I'm trying to create a vba script in an excel document in order to compare Word documents versions and create summary Word documents with the differences (track changes).

Here my script:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ButtonSummaryReport_Click()
    'Initialize the progressbar and the label
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim filesNumber As Integer
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim objFolderAPath As String
    Dim objFolderBPath As String
    Dim objFolderCPath As String
    
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WDApp As Object 'Word.Application
    Dim WDDocA As Object 'Word.Document
    Dim WDDocB As Object 'Word.Document
    Dim WDDocC As Object 'Word.Document
    
    'Declare variable
    Dim objFSOA As Object
    Dim objFSOB As Object
    Dim objFSOC As Object
    Dim objFolderA As Object
    Dim objFolderB As Object
    Dim objFolderC As Object
    Dim colFilesA As Object
    Dim objFileA As Object
    Dim PathFileA As String
    Dim PathFileB As String
    Dim PathFileC As String
    
    Dim wordapp
    
    k = 0
    Me.LabelSummaryReport.Caption = "Please wait..."
    Me.ProgressBarSummaryReport.Value = k
    
 
    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSOA = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFSOB = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFSOC = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Select the path for the 3 folders
    Set objFolderA = objFSOA.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with the original documents"))
    objFolderAPath = objFolderA.Path
    Debug.Print objFolderAPath
    
    Set objFolderB = objFSOB.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with revised documents"))
    objFolderBPath = objFolderB.Path
    Debug.Print objFolderBPath
    
    Set objFolderC = objFSOC.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder for the comparisons documents"))
    objFolderCPath = objFolderC.Path
    Debug.Print objFolderCPath


    Set colFilesA = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFileA = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set colFilesA = objFolderA.Files
    
    'Turn off DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
 
    'Number of files in the folder
    filesNumber = objFolderA.Files.Count
       
    Me.LabelSummaryReport.Caption = "The comparison process starts..."
    For Each objFileA In colFilesA


    PathFileA = objFolderA.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
    Debug.Print PathFileA
    PathFileB = objFolderB.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
    Debug.Print PathFileB
    PathFileC = objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
    Debug.Print PathFileC
    
    If objFileA.Name Like "*.docx" Then
                    
        'Creating object of the word application
        Set WDApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
        
        'Making visible the word application
        WDApp.Visible = True
        
        'Opening the required word document
        Set WDDocA = WDApp.Documents.Open(PathFileA)
        

        'Opening the required word document
        Set WDDocB = WDApp.Documents.Open(PathFileB)
               
        WDApp.CompareDocuments _
        OriginalDocument:=WDDocA, _
        RevisedDocument:=WDDocB, _
        Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew, _
        IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings:=False
        
        WDDocA.Close
        WDDocB.Close
        'On Error Resume Next
        'Kill objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        'On Error GoTo 0
        
        'Turn off DisplayAlerts
        WDApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
       
        Set WDDocC = WDApp.ActiveDocument
        WDDocC.SaveAs FileName:=PathFileC
        WDDocC.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If

        'Update of the progressbar and the label
        k = k + 1
        Me.LabelSummaryReport.Caption = k * 100 / filesNumber & "% Completed"
        Me.ProgressBarSummaryReport.Value = k * 100 / filesNumber
        
    Next objFileA
    Me.LabelSummaryReport.Caption = "The process is complete. Comparison reports have been created."
End Sub


Function ChooseFolder(title) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .title = title
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

I have a problem when saving the summary document with track changes. This report cannot be saved. I don't know exactly how to solve that.

Could you please help me to solve this issue and optimize this code if necessary.

Comment: In which line do you get the error? In `WDDocC.SaveAs FileName:=PathFileC` this? Did you check the `PathFileC`?

Comment: There's a [Compare](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-document-differences-using-the-legal-blackline-option-dbfc7351-4022-43a2-a0c4-54d1898702a0#:~:text=The%20legal%20blackline%20option%20compares,do%20not%20select%20this%20option.) button on the Review tab along with a [Track Changes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/track-changes-in-word-197ba630-0f5f-4a8e-9a77-3712475e806a) button.

Comment: See https://www.excelforum.com/word-programming-vba-macros/1314685-need-help-to-browse-by-file-msofiledialogfilepicker-instead-by-folder.html#post5323754 for comparing two documents with a third as the output document, and https://www.msofficeforums.com/133132-post2.html for exporting the tracked revisions to Excel

Comment: The pathFIleC is correct. In fact when the command 'WDDocA.Close' and 'DDDocB.Close' are done, all Word documents are closed (the summary report also) I obtained the issue with the command 'Set WDDocC = ActiveDocument'

Comment: @coeurdange57 see my answer below. You don't see your issues because you are not using `Option Explicit`. If you use it and declare all your variables properly you will be notified that some "variables" are not declared like `wdAlertsNone` in Excel (they only exist in Word).

Comment: Hi, I get a new issue: When the document A and B are closed, the new summary document is also closed, someone could help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `Option Explicit` to see your problems.

> I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. So you have it activated automatically in all your new codes.

If you use late binding like `Set WDApp = CreateObject("word.Application")` all the Word enumeration constants like `wdAlertsNone` and `wdCompareDestinationNew` do not exist in Excel.

So either you need to

- define them first in Excel
- or use early binding (by setting a reference to Word in the Extras > References menu)
- or replace all wd constants with their specific `Long` value. See [Word Enumerated Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211923(v=office.11))

Further you need to `Set WDDocC = WDApp.ActiveDocument` because Excel expects `ActiveDocument` to be something in Excel and there it doesn't exist, it only exists in Word. You need to specify that you mean the `ActiveDocument` of the Word application `WDApp`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in vba. Here I don't know how to solve the issue for saving the file, because when I close the both documents to compare, the summary report is also closed, and so the system cannot save...

Comment: @coeurdange57 Did you change it to `Set WDDocC = WDApp.ActiveDocument`? What have you done? Please be more precise. Making the changes I suggested worked here.

Comment: please see my post below

Comment: @coeurdange57 please don't post questions as answers. If you want to add something to your question please edit the original question. Answer should only contain solutions to the original question (or they get deleted by the commuinty).

Comment: I updated my original post with updates of the script. I have still the same issue. On the line for saving the file, I have the error "Application-defined or object-defined error": `Set WDDocC = WDApp.ActiveDocument
        WDDocC.Save As FileName:=PathFileC
        WDDocC.Close SaveChanges:=True`